# How Shadow Copy Service works? how it backups the data which we modified

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, volume-shadow-copy, vss

I am Using Shadow Copy to restore my files,and restoring my files. I wonder how does it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hardware or software shadow copy provider uses one of the following methods for creating a shadow copy:

Complete copy   This method makes a complete copy (called a "full copy" or "clone") of the original volume at a given point in time. This copy is read-only.

Copy-on-write   This method does not copy the original volume. Instead, it makes a differential copy by copying all changes (completed write I/O requests) that are made to the volume after a given point in time.

Redirect-on-write   This method does not copy the original volume, and it does not make any changes to the original volume after a given point in time. Instead, it makes a differential copy by redirecting all changes to a different volume.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the way shadow copy works is by placing a marker on the hard drive at the point of a snapshot so that when yu open a file and work on it further, it is actually saved again to a different part of the physical drive.  When you do a restore, the older copy of the file is marked as active and the newer version discarded.